# Is a small number of dropped packets a problem?

Tags: linux, networking

I have some dropped RX packets, about 1 per second, is it a problem, or normal?

```
# ifconfig enp37s0f0 | grep RX ; sleep 1 ; ifconfig enp37s0f0 | grep RX
        RX packets 17434229869  bytes 16200709740141 (16.2 TB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 381182  overruns 0  frame 0
        RX packets 17434256937  bytes 16200736736790 (16.2 TB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 381183  overruns 0  frame 0
```

Comment: It kind of depends on your situation . On one hand, any number of dropped packets  can be called a problem, on the other hand it's below 1 in 27000 packets that get dropped, so your connection works.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot judge without telling what these packets are.
I suggest that you first investigate with simple tools such as iptraf-ng or, if you like overkilling with wireshark.

If you see TCP / UDP packets incoming with your IP address or broadcast, then yes! something is going wrong.

But, it can be totally normal if, as I did on my system, you configured your system to drop (for example) IGMP packets. In which case, if your dropped packets are IGMP, everything is absolutely normal.

In addition, contrarily to what being written in another answer, dropped packets are not an indication that your system is receiving more traffic that the system can handle. Overruns are and your count is 0.

Answer (score -1):

In general, a small number of dropped packets (relative to total received packets) is not a big deal.

However, any dropped packets can be an indicator that your system is receiving more traffic than it can handle.  If there are higher speed devices on your network, this is to be expected, as network protocols (and TCP in particular) are designed to send packets faster until some are dropped and then throttle.  But it is still an indicator your network speed could be faster if your device was faster.

There are other reasons packets could be dropped, so it's not a sure indicator, especially for small numbers.

Comment: No : dropped packets is not an indicator that your system is receiving more traffic that the system can handle. Overruns are and OPs count of overruns is 0

Comment: Actually, overruns is a *worse* problem than dropped packets and is a sure sign there is something wrong.  Unless packets are intentionally dropped, it's a sign things are too slow, but not an alarming one.